# VMWare Installer unable to load gtk: No module named gtk, falling back to console

Tags: vmware, gtk

I'm new to Ubuntu (20.10) and just installed it on my Raspberry Pi 400. I have my VMWare-Horizon-Client-2006-8.0.0-16522670.x64.bundle in the home directory.

I'm following this guide [Install or Upgrade Horizon Client for Linux from VMware Product Downloads](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Horizon-Client-for-Linux/2006/horizon-client-linux-installation/GUID-F563F1E1-D9BD-4C42-80DC-4A3EB015FD65.html) in order to install VMWare Horizon Client 2006 8.0.0 and keep getting the error "Unable to load gtk: No module named gtk, falling back to console."

While I know that VMWare Horizon says it can run on 20.04, could the reason be 20.10 is too new? The Pi400 doesn't have a 20.04 in the standard imager but I just figured it should work.

Otherwise, I think I might be missing these steps:

- Confirm that version 2.x or 3.x of Python is installed on the client
  system. If the system does not have the Python 2.x or 3.x package,
  run the necessary command to install it.
- If you are using a thin client, confirm that libgtk 3.14 or later is installed on the system. If needed, obtain version 3.14 or later of the libgtk library and install it on the thin-client system.

However, I am not sure how to perform them in the terminal (sudo apt-get install python, and sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk-module does not give me the gtk module). Any thoughts on what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

I followed the guide to uninstall and re-ran the command line installation and it was successful. Still not clear what the issue was!